# Create virtual host + MySQL tool

Tags: python, object-oriented

This tool adds a new OS user, create directories and configuration files for Apache + NGINX, MySQL (MariaDB) database and user.

I tried to take into account the comments from my [previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61798/mysql-class-to-add-user-database). Hope - this look little better.

Tool is big enough, so - will not post all it's code here, just few main parts - I'm sure, there is some places to improve (as I'm newbie in Python). Full version available [here](http://rtfm.co.ua/python-utilita-dlya-sozdaniya-novogo-apache-virtualhost-polzovatel-baza-mysql/).

First - some classes.

Next class takes TEMPLATE file, and edit it to create new `virtualhost` config:

```
class MainClass(object):

        user = None

        def __init__(self, user, password, domain):
                self.user = user
                self.password = password
                self.domain = domain
    ...
class SystemOperations(MainClass):
    ...
    def createconf(self, configin, configout, oflist):
            self.configin = configin
            self.configout = configout
            self.oflist = oflist
            tolist = (self.user, self.domain)

            shutil.copy(self.configin, self.configout)

            for of, to in zip(self.oflist, tolist):
                    with open(self.configout, 'r') as infile:
                            data = infile.readlines()

                    with open(self.configout, 'w') as infile:
                            for string in data:
                                    infile.write(re.sub(of, to, string))
     ...
```

And it's call inside script:

```
    ...
    # used when creates Apache and NGINX configuration files
    config_dirs = ('/etc/httpd/conf.d/', '/etc/nginx/conf.d/')
    ...
    ## create config file
    # data which will looking for
    # in template configs to change it
    oflist = ('USER', 'DOMAIN')
    # will change to this variables
    tolist = (user, domain)

    # for both Apache and NGINX config dirs
    for i in config_dirs:
            # create var with name of template file
            configin = i + 'TEMPLATE'
            # creat var with name of new config file
            configout = i + domain + '.conf'
            print('\nCreating new configuration file %s.' % configout)
            if not os.path.isfile(configout):
                    try:
                            sysacts.createconf(configin, configout, oflist)
                            print('Done.')
                    except IOError as e:
                            print('ERROR: %s' %e)
                            sys.exit(6)
            else:
                    print('File %s already present, skipping.' % configout)
     ...
```

As example - Apache TEMPLATE file:

```
# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/TEMPLATE
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/USER/DOMAIN
  ServerName DOMAIN
  ServerAlias www.DOMAIN
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/DOMAIN-access.log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/DOMAIN-error.log

  <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    SuexecUserGroup USER USER
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/USER/DOMAIN>
      Options +ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      AddHandler fcgid-script .php
      FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-cgi/USER/DOMAIN/php.cgi .php
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

And second part - MySQL user and database creation.

Its class:

...
    class mysqlUserDb(MainClass):

```
        warnings.filterwarnings('error')

        def __init__(self, dbroot, dbhost, dbrootpw, *args):
                super(mysqlUserDb, self).__init__(*args)

                self.dbroot = dbroot
                self.dbhost = dbhost
                self.dbrootpw = dbrootpw

                self.db = MySQLdb.connect(self.dbhost, self.dbroot, self.dbrootpw)
                self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

        def createdb(self, dbuserdb):

                self.dbuserdb = dbuserdb

                self.cursor.execute('create database if not exists ' + self.dbuserdb)
                self.cursor.execute("show databases like '%s' " % self.dbuserdb)
                self.dbs = self.cursor.fetchone()
                return self.dbs
  ...
```

And its call in script:

```
if options.mysql:

        print('\nStarting MySQL actions.')

        if options.dbrootpw == None:
                dbrootpw = getpass.getpass('\nPlease, enter MySQL root password: ')


        # we must have database name
        if dbuserdb == None:
                print('\nERROR! please, set `-m` option with User database name.\n')
                sys.exit(7)

        warnings.filterwarnings('error')

        # Open and check MySQL connection
        try:
                dbconnect = fun.mysqlUserDb(dbroot, dbhost, dbrootpw, user, password, domain)
                print('Connection opened successfully.')
        except MySQLdb.Error as e:
                print('MySQL error: %s \nExit.\n' % e)
                sys.exit(8)

        # create database
        try:
                print('\nCreating database %s.' % dbuserdb)
                dbconnect.createdb(dbuserdb)
                print 'Database created: %s' % dbconnect.dbs
        except Warning as error:
                print('MySQL warning: %s' % error)
        except MySQLdb.Error as e:
                print('MySQL error: %s \nExit.\n' % e)
                sys,exit(9)

        # add user and grant prielegies
        try:
                print('\nAdding privilegies to user %s with password %s to database %s.' % (user, password, dbuserdb))
                dbconnect.grants(dbuserdb)
                print('Access granted: %r' % dbconnect.grs)
        except MySQLdb.Error as e:
                print('MySQL error: %s \nExit.\n' % e)
                sys,exit(10)
    # close connection
    print('\nFinishing MySQL actions...')
    del dbconnect
    print 'Done.\n'

else:
    print('Skipping MySQL actions.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user = None` here is pointless, confusing, and you're not using it anyway, so just drop it:

> ```
> class MainClass(object):
>
>         user = None
>
>         def __init__(self, user, password, domain):
>                 self.user = user
> ```

---

There are multiple inefficiencies here:

> ```
> shutil.copy(self.configin, self.configout)
>
> for of, to in zip(self.oflist, tolist):
>         with open(self.configout, 'r') as infile:
>                 data = infile.readlines()
>
>         with open(self.configout, 'w') as infile:
>                 for string in data:
>                         infile.write(re.sub(of, to, string))
> ```

1. You copy a file with `shutil.copy`, but then you rewrite it anyway in the loop.
2. For each `of, to` pair, you rewrite the output file
3. You apply the pattern substitution line by line

Refactor like this:

1. Drop the `shutil.copy` step
2. Read from the input file into a buffer, instead of getting its lines
3. Loop over the `of, to` pairs, and apply the pattern substitutions to the data buffer
4. Write the output file

---

This is not Pythonic:

> ```
> if options.dbrootpw == None:
>     # ...
>
> if dbuserdb == None:
>     # ...
> ```

Write like this:

```
if not options.dbrootpw:
    # ...

if not dbuserdb:
    # ...
```

---

Some of your variable names are really not so good, for example:

> ```
> for i in config_dirs:
> ```

`i` is commonly used for loop counters. In general, avoid single-letter variable names. In this example, `path` would have been a better name.